# simple express and socket example does not work

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

i use express 4 with socket.io.

when server is running, socket does not work.

console does not print 'user connect'.

client button does not work.

please help me. :-(

this is my code

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
 res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});

module.exports = app;
```

**io.js**

```
var io = require('socket.io')();

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
 console.log('user connected');
 socket.on('rint', function(data) {
  console.log('user send data : ' + data);
  socket.emit('smart', data);
 });
});

module.exports = io;
```

**/bin/www**

```
\#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var io = require('../io');
var debug = require('debug')('socketT:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);
io.attach(server);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

...
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
 <script>
  window.onload = function() {
   var socket = io();
   socket.on('smart', function(data) {
    alert(data);
   });
   document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
    var text = document.getElementById('text').value;
    socket.emit('rint', text);
   });
  });
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <input type="text" id="text" />
 <input type="button" id="button" value="echo" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your listener for everything on the server-side is on("connection", ... but you don't make that connection anywhere on the client side.

Check out the following page: http://socket.io/docs/

You will need to add the url of the server you are connecting:

index.html:

```
 var socket = io("localhost:8080"); //Or whatever your url and port are.
```